# Evaluating variance of scale parameter estimators

Tags: estimation, variance, parameter-estimation

> Let $\{Y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be a random sample of the random variable $Y_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2})$, we define the following estimators for $\sigma^{2}$
>
> $U=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_{i}-\bar{Y})^{2} \quad V = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\left( (n-2)\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2} + (n\bar{Y})^{2}\right)$
>
> Show that they have same variance.

First of all, I showed that they are both unbiased estimators of $\sigma^{2}$ and the complete statistic for this case is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}$ using the open set condition for the exponential family. However they aren't functions of the sample **only** through $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}$. I don't think the person that wrote the exercise wanted the reader to calculate the variance directly, I'm guessing I missed something along the way. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Since $T=\sum Y_i^2$ is complete sufficient and $\frac{T}{n}$ is the UMVUE of $\sigma^2$, we do have $E(U\mid T)=E(V\mid T)=\frac{T}{n}$ by Lehmann-Scheffe. But I don't think it makes things any easier if you were to use something like $\operatorname{Var}(U)=E(\operatorname{Var}(U\mid T))+\operatorname{Var}(E(U\mid T))$. Direct calculation looks easier.

Comment: Using conditionals might help, because the 2nd term is the Cramer Rao Lower Bound, isn't it?

Comment: What about the first term?